# Opposite of Oracle "ALTER SYSTEM SET" Command

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking at some code and I see that someone is writing the following pl/sql.

```
alter system set smtp_out_server = '123.345.134.123';
```

Since this is the mutator (setter), what's the accessor (getter) of this command?

SELECT what from where to view the SMTP_OUT_SERVER setting?

Thanks,

mj

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
select *
  from V$PARAMETER
 where NAME = 'smtp_out_server';
```

Or, in an `sqlplus` session you can type:

```
show parameter smtp_out_server
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from v$parameter
```

That should get the settings, add a where clause for the specific one you are after